# How am I able to pass setState in a stateless widget from a statefull widget

Tags: function, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In the below code I have passed set state as a function call in a stateless widget how is this possible I know there is nothing wrong with flutter, but its something about the functions in general, I am not getting the basics right can someone plz explain me this concept.
Comments are provided for assistance.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {    //STATEFUL WIDGET
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Demo(function: () {
            setState(() {});      //PASSING SET STATE
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {  //STATE  LESS WIDGET
  final Function function;
  Demo({this.function});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Refer this demo example for passing the value either in State or stateless https://stackoverflow.com/a/61743422/3946958

Comment: no, the problem is how can I pass set state call in a stateless widget as stateless widget doesn't know what is set state so how can I pass it as an argument. I know I can pass but (why) is my question

Comment: so is `Demo(function: () {
            setState(() {});      //PASSING SET STATE
          });` working or you have any problem with  passing such a callback to some other widget?

Comment: it's working fine even I have developed a full-fledged app but the question is (how ).

Comment: have you used any `RaisedButton` / `OutlineButton` / `FlatButton`? they have `onPressed` property - this is exactly the same - you are passing some function to that button and when the click is performed tha button calls that callback function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState()` is a method inside the `State` class. In your code you have the following:

```
   onPressed: () {
          Demo(function: () {
            setState(() {});      //PASSING SET STATE
          });
        },
```

Here you create an instance of `Demo` and give it a callback as an argument. Inside that callback, you are calling `setState` which is a method inside the `State` class.

Comment: I am not getting the callback thing plz elaborate a bit how it works in this case.

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504089/7015400

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma @UTKARSHSharma for ex in javascript `function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
  callback();
}
doHomework('math', function() {
  alert('Finished my homework');
});` Here, the function `doHomework` takes a subject variable and function reference `callback`. After the alert appears and you know the subject, then the function (callback) will be called. So basically a callback is a function that is called as a response of something occurring. It can be a response of a click on a button or as a response of retrieving data from the db

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma so a callback is not called immediately, it is a function that is called in response to something occurring. Thats why its called "callback", you can think about it as call me later. All buttons in flutter, use callback functions and these functions are called in response to when the user clicks the button. All asynchronous code in flutter uses callback and these callbacks are called when the data is retrieved

Answer (score 2):

In Dart, methods and functions can be passed around just as though they were normal variables and values. In this case, you have passed the `setState` method from the stateful widget into the constructor of the stateless widget. (Or, more precisely, you have wrapped a call to the stateful widget's `setState` in an anonymous function and then passed *that* function to the stateless widget.)

This can be demonstrated more simply in the following way:

```dart
class A {
  int x = 0;

  void doThing() {
    x = 5;
  }
}

class B {
  Function f;

  B(this.f);

  void runFunction() {
    f();
  }
}

// ...

A a = A();
B b = B(a.doThing);
b.runFunction();
print(a.x);

// Prints: 5
```

In this example, the `doThing` from `a` is passed into `b`, which assigns it to `b.f`. When `b` calls `f`, it is the same as calling `a.doThing` directly, which can be shown by `a.x` having the updated value after the fact. This is what is known as passing a *callback*, which is a function passed to another function or object that can then be called without having to reference the passed-in function directly. i.e. `b` can call `a.doThing` by calling the callback `f()` without having to explicitly call `a.doThing()`. *(Note: this is a very simplistic explanation of a callback, and a more detailed explanation goes into the nuance of how the passed function is actually used.)*

This is not the same as saying that `a.doThing` now belongs to `b`, and `b` does not now magically have a `doThing` method. Likewise, when you pass in `setValue` to a stateless widget, you are not magically granting that widget a state and you are not breaking the rules of Flutter by suddenly being able to call "`setState`" from a stateless widget any more than if you had passed an instance of the `State<MyApp>` itself and called `stateObj.setState(...)` directly (not that I am recommending you do that, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example:
we have a class contains a function which require `setState` and want to use that function from a stateful widget, so I can pass that function by following way.

```
class Api {
  static bool isLoading = false;
// want to use setState in this function

  static Future<void> getApiResponse({
    required Function(bool) function, //here I setState bool = true so I write bool
  }) async {
    // setState
    function(true);
    try {
      //TODO: some code
      // setState
      function(false);
    } catch (e) {
      //setState
      function(false);
      throw e;
    }
  }
}

// function in stateful widget
Future<void> func1() async {
  await Api.getApiResponse(
    function: (bool value) {
      setState(() {
        Api.isLoading = value;
      });
    },
  );
}
```