# In Flutter How to pass value to the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am in learning phase of Flutter and I need to identify which **_buildTile** I have clicked to write the functionality based on my click how to do this.

My two **_buildTile** are as below

```
 _buildTile(
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
            child: Column
              (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>
                [
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0)),
                  Text('Cash Received', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18.0)),
                  Text('25,000.00', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 28.0)),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),

_buildTile(
          Padding
            (
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
            child: Column
              (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>
                [
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0)),
                  Text('Cash Spent', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18.0)),
                  Text('9,000.00', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 28.0)),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

In the below function how to get which **_buildTile** I have clicked how to pass value can any one help me

```
Widget _buildTile(Widget child, {Function() onTap}) {
return Material(
    elevation: 14.0,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
    child: InkWell
      (
      // Do onTap() if it isn't null, otherwise do print()
        onTap: onTap != null ? () => onTap() : () { print('Which _buildTile I clicked'); },
        child: child
    )
);}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to pass multiple index arguments to another screen using pushNamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742331/is-there-a-way-to-pass-multiple-index-arguments-to-another-screen-using-pushname)

Comment: No this is not  having index to pass and get value. or I don't know how to pass index value to this. I am new and in learning phase. The above link give to use  constructor also which I know. But this is with in a class and I don't know how it gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just pass some Identifier to your `_buildTile()`?

```
 _buildTile(
          child: Padding( //This is your "Widget child Argument"
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
            child: Column
              (
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>
                [
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0)),
                  Text('Cash Received', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18.0)),
                  Text('25,000.00', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 28.0)),
                ]
            ),
          ),
          //Under the Widget you are passing as your first argument, you pass the others
          tileNumber: 1, //You can change the identifier here for each Tile you make
        ),
```

And here the buildTile();

```
Widget _buildTile({Widget child, {Function() onTap}, int tileNumber}) {
return Material(
    elevation: 14.0,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
    child: InkWell
      (
      // Do onTap() if it isn't null, otherwise do print()
        onTap: onTap != null ? () => onTap() : () { print("clicked tile #" + tileNumber) },
        child: child
    )
);}
```

Note the extra {} i put in the () of _buildTile(), these make your arguments into named arguments. meaning you can more easily see what argument you are passing. You can see that in action by the "child: Padding" instead of just "Padding".

Comment: Thanks for  your response. But as I said I am in Learning I don't know how to change my code in the upper part to send the value to the function. I know and understand the lower part that you have given I need to know the upper part

Comment: @VijayanandPremnath I Updated my answer with some more detail and code. Hope it helps!